# Scipy libraries won't load into berryconda version of jupyter

Tags: scipy, jupyter-notebook

I just installed Berryconda which is now supported from Anaconda, but I successfully install the scipy libraries "pandas, numpy, matplotlib" but my kernel for some reason either isn't using anaconda kernel so it isn't loading the libaries from anaconda and loading the default rasberry pi libraries or I can't think of any other explanation.

Do I need to add a PYTHONPATH enviroment variable in raspberry pi?  How do I do that.

so

```
import pandas as pd
```

fails

```
import numpy as np
```

fails and

```
%matplotlib inline
```

fails